# uipanel object and figure parent relation

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am making a gui which includes parent figure window, and in which its child is a `uipanel` object.  In the uipanel object I am plotting trends of some variables.

The problem I am facing is that when I click mouse in figure window anywhere apart from the area of uipanel display, my uipanel display gets disturbed and doesn't show anything.

I am not too sure what to do. I have tried using `Interruptible` property but couldn't find solution.

Comment: What do you mean it gets disturbed? If you show some code, you will likely get a solution quicker.

Comment: Get disturbed means in normal case my uipanel showing a normal plot but when i click outside uipanel window, the plot inside uipanel doesn't show me trend of variable. Code is too big to show.